# Kotlin RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations attribute: MyType(String)

Tags: android, enums, kotlin

I have a problem with parametric enums in Kotlin, after integration with Dagger2 I got RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotaions attribute: MyType(String) exception during compile time. Any ideas how to fix that? Non parametric enums works like a charm

MyType:

```
enum class MyType
constructor(val value: String) {
  ABC("123"), DEF("456");
}
```

Kotlin 1.0.2 with kapt generateStubs = true

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Kotlin: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12694